# Cityscapes Trafficsigns no box- or mask- detection with TF Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, object-recognition, object-detection-api

I'd be thankful for all thoughts, tips or links on this:

Using TF 1.10 and the recent [object detection-API (github, 2018-08-18)](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/instance_segmentation.md) I can do box- and mask prediction using the PETS dataset as well as using my own proof of concept data-set: [image: Mask result]

---

But when training on the cityscapes traffic signs (single class) I am having troubles to achieve *any* results. I have adapted the anchors to respect the much smaller objects and it seems the RPN is doing *something useful* at least: [image: RPN after 17k steps]

Anyway, the box predictor is not going into action at all. That means I am not getting any boxes at all - not to ask for masks.

---

My pipelines are mostly or even exactly like the sample configs. 
So I'd expect either problems with the specific type of data or a bug .

Would you have any tips/links how to (either)

- visualize the RPN results when using 2 or 3 stages? (Using only one stage does that, but how would one force that?)
- train the RPN first and continue with boxes later?
- investigate where/why the boxes get lost? (having predictions with **zero** scores while evaluation yields **zero** classification error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution finally was a combination of multiple issues:

[image: Results already showing after only a few epochs]

- The parameter `from_detection_checkpoint: true` is depreciated and to be replaced by `fine_tune_checkpoint_type: 'detection'`. However, without any of those the framework seems to default to `'classification'`, what seems to break the whole idea of the object detection framework. No good idea to rely on the defaults this time.
- My data wasn't prepared good enough. I had boxes with zero width+/height (for whatever reason). I also removed masks for instances that were disconnected.
- Using the `keep_aspect_ratio_resizer` together with `random_crop_image` and `random_coef: 0.0` does *not* seem to allow for the full resolution as the resizer seems to be applied before the random cropping. I do now split my input images into (vertical) stripes [for memory saving] and apply the random_crop with a small `min_area` so it does not skip the small features at all. Also I can now allow for a `max_area: 1` and a random coefficient > 0, as the memory usage is dealt with.
- One potential problem also arose from the fact that I only considered a single class (so far). This might be a problem either for the framework, or for the activation function in the network. However, in combination with the other issues this change seemed to cause no additional problems - at minimum.
- Last but not least I updated the sources to 2018-10-02 but didn't walk through all modifications in detail.

I hope others can save time and troubles from my findings.